# ¿acceder a ementos de un list<> unity?

Tags: unity3d

En un `array` puedo acceder a los elementos por medio de la clave

```
arraay[elemtno]
```

Pero en una `list` como accedo a cada elemento ya que no peudo hacer

```
 list[elemento]
```

Si tienen una idea, le agradezco su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Con el `get` y el numero del index puede obtener el valor ejemplo...

```
list.get[0];
```

espero te AYUDE ReNiceCode....

Comment: Las listas no tienen ese método.

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a una lista generica puedes usar el index. 
En una lista generica se organizan de 0 a N - 1. A diferencia de un hashmap o diccionario que se guardan por claves y sin un orden especifico.

```
public List<Object> Objetos = new List<Object>();
Objetos[index].parametros = nuevo_valor
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder exactamente como lo haces con los arreglos:

```
List<string> somelist=new List<string>();
Debug.LogWarning(somelist[3]);
```